# How to interpolate Matricies in a opengl Tessalation Evaluation shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Can't find this anywhere on the internet. Using the tessalation evaluation shader, I can interpolate values for a vec2 or vec3 like so:

```
vec3 interpolate3D(vec3 v0, vec3 v1, vec3 v2)
{
return vec3(gl_TessCoord.x) * v0 + vec3(gl_TessCoord.y) * v1 +vec3(gl_TessCoord.z) * v2;
}
```

How do I do the same to pass in and interpolate a matrix? Wanting this for the tangent matrix for normal mapping and for the transform matrix to calculate the new vertex normals from a heightmap. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to construct a vector from a scalar to compute the product of a vector and the scalar. It is possible to multiply a vector by scalar. If a vector is multiplied by a scalar, each component of the vector is multiplied by the scalar.
Note, if both sides of a binary operator (like `*`, `+`) are vectors (with same size), then the operation is performed component-wise. If one side is a vector and the other side is a scalar, then the operation is applied to all components of the vector.
See [Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations).

So the expression from your question can be written as:

```c
return v0 * gl_TessCoord.x + v1 * gl_TessCoord.y + v2 * gl_TessCoord.z;
```

The same rules apply to matrices. Even matrices can be multiplied by a scalar and summed component-wise. If `m0`, `m1` and `m2` are of type `mat3`, then you can do:

```c
mat3 m = m0 * gl_TessCoord.x + m1 * gl_TessCoord.y + m2 * gl_TessCoord.z;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much :)